# Conceptual / Rule Implementation / String Manipulation

Tags: vb.net, string, rules, rule-engine

So I'm working on a software in VB.Net where I need to scrape information and process it according to rules. For example, simple string replace rules like making "Det" into "Detached" for a specific field, or a split/join rule, basic string operations. All my scraping rules are RegEx and I store them in a database in rows of rule sets for different situations.

What is the best way behind creating/storing rules to manipulate text? I do not want to hardcode the rules into the software, but rather be able to add more as there will be a need for them. I want to store them in a database, but then how do I interpret them? I'm assuming I would have to create a whole system to interpret them, like a rules engine? Maybe you can give me a different outlook on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written rules engines before.  They are usually a Bad Idea (tm).

I would consider writing the rules in your application code.  Leave the database and rules engine out of it.  First, a rules engine often confuses intent.  It's hard to see exactly what is going on when you come back in a couple months for a maintenance patch.  Second, VB (or C# or any other language you choose) contains a more appropriate vocabulary for defining rules than anything you will likely have time to implement.  Trust me, XML is a poor representation of rules.  Lastly, non-programmers won't be able to write regex anyhow.. so you aren't gaining anything for all your added complexity.

You can mitigate most of the deployment headaches by using ClickOnce deployment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nonsense. Your entire answer is a complete nonsense. If anything of it would be true, we would still live in the stone age. Banks wouldn't work, planes wouldn't fly, etc, etc. Business rules are a HUGE part of modern programming and data analysis. You are mixing business rules with a small and trivial task of string manipulation. Boo.

Comment: Well, you are of course entitled to your opinion.  I stand by my answer with two decades of experience backing it.

Comment: I kinda agree with Kizz... I don't need anyone else other than me to develop the rules and they wouldn't be RegEx, however they would encompass a lot of string manipulation and rather than modifying the source code every time I want to add a rule, I'd rather create a system to which I can simply add rules (in a database) and see the outcome. All the rules however would be limited by the complexity of the engine... but the whole idea is to get away from internal code... But I'd like to know whether that makes sense or not. Maybe I'm just stuck on this idea that won't bring any benefits?

Comment: @Theveloper: I would encourage you to go ahead and build it.  But after you do, and have used it for 6 months, revisit the implementation and see if you would have done anything differently.  Everyone has a different idea of what's "easier".  For me, changing the source is easier.  Someone comes along and says, "Hey Boo, this app you developped is acting in a manner inconsistant with my expectations" (or that's what I want them to say.. usually its filled with a few more expletives).. so I open the code and.. hmm.. lookit that.. all my rules are right there for perusal.

Comment: @Theveloper: of course, I've had the other happen.. I built a rules engine.. and now I open the code in response to a bug complaint.. and.. DOH.. I can't tell exactly what's going on because the rules are in the database.. so open the database.. and.. yikes.. find the rows that match condition X and the related rows that control the rules.. and... it's not "easy" to me.   But this is my opinion and everyone has their own.

Comment: gotcha! thanks Boo, Happy New Year! I'm going to write the rules engine, with a bit of a "logistical" mindset developing a db for them shouldn't  be that hard but it is a limitation if I wanna have the db normalized and having dynamic conditions for the different types of rules that apply is going to be a little bit harder to implement but I think it's the most tidy way of going about it! Thanks for your time.